# How does `Hash#sort{|a, b| block}` work?

Tags: ruby

In ruby-doc I see this example:

```
h = { "a" => 20, "b" => 30, "c" => 10  }
h.sort {|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}   #=> [["c", 10], ["a", 20], ["b", 30]]
```

Can anyone explain what `a[1]<=>b[1]` means? What are we comparing here? Is `a` is  a key and `b` its value? Why we are comparing index `1`?

Comment: I understand what "<=>" means. But why there is a[1] not a[0] ?

Comment: They are indexes of the array `a` : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements

Comment: I know they are indices. but where does the array comes from? I have edited my question and please remove that "duplicate mark".@IvanGabriele

Comment: @user2864740Thanks. As you said a would be keys, and b would be values, but how we are comparing the index 1 of array of keys to index 1 at array of values? I'm totally lost.

Comment: @assiegee That is not what the user said. `a` is [key, value], and `b` is as well.

Comment: @sawa Got it thanks. I confused it with "h.each"

Comment: You could also write `h.sort { |(k1, v1), (k2, v2)| v1<=>v2 }`. If you wish to draw attention to the fact that the keys are not used by the block, you could write the block variables as `|(_, v1), (_, v2)|` or  `|(_k1, v1),(_k2, v2)|`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That make things clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `b` are both arrays of `[key, value]` which *come from [`Hash#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-sort)*.

> Converts hsh to a nested array of [ key, value ] arrays and sorts it, using Array#sort.

So `a[1]<=>b[1]` sorts the resulting pairs by the *value*. If it were `a[0]<=>b[0]` it would be sorting by the *key*.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have a key-value-pair or tuple datatype, so *all* `Hash` iteration methods (`each`, `map`, `select`, `sort`, …) represent hash entries as an `Array` with two elements, `[key, value]`. (In fact, most methods aren't even implemented in `Hash`, they are inherited from `Enumerable` and don't even know anything about keys and values.)

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on this:

```
h = { "a" => 20, "b" => 30, "c" => 10  }
h.sort { |a,b| # => {"a"=>20, "b"=>30, "c"=>10}
  a[1]<=>b[1]
}              # => [["c", 10], ["a", 20], ["b", 30]]
```

For each loop of the key/value pairs in `h`, Ruby passes each key/value pair into the block as an array of two elements.